# How to use vue-router with a predefined template

Tags: vue-router, vuetify.js

I have added a link in my items object

```js
items: [
  { icon: 'dashboard' text: 'Home', link: '/'},
  { icon: 'dashboard' text: 'Account', link: '/account'},
]
```

Where do I put the router-link component?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`v-list-tile`, `v-btn`, and `v-card` all extend `router-link`, so you can use any of the `router-link` attributes directly on those components instead.

In your case you can just use `<v-list-tile :to="item.link">`

Comment: Where can we find documentation on this?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with a params object though, is there something i'm missing? `<v-list-tile @click="" :to="{path: '/settings', params: {jumpTo: 'verification'}}">` gives empty object on `this.$route.params`

Comment: i found out it actually doesn't with `path`, only works with `name` iirc

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and I solved it like this:

```html
<v-list-item v-else :key="item.text" link>
<!-- to -->
<v-list-item v-else :key="item.text" :to="item.link" link>
    
    
<v-list-item v-for="(child, i) in item.children" :key="i" link>
<!-- to -->
<v-list-item v-for="(child, i) in item.children" :key="i" :to="child.link" link>
```

```js
{ icon: "mdi-history", text: "Recientes", link: "/" },
```

Don't forget to put `<router-view />` in the container.

```html
<v-content>
  <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
    <router-view />
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew there's an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**An example:**

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    app
    clipped
    permanent
    expand-on-hover
  >
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/85.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-list-item link>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title class="title">Sandra Adams</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>sandra_a88@gmail.com</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-list
      nav
      dense
    >
      <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :to="item.link" link>
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon>{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
        <v-list-item-title>{{item.text}}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MenuDrawer',

  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        icon: 'mdi-folder',
        text: 'Home',
        link: '/',
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-account-multiple',
        text: 'Starred',
        link: 'https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify',
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-star',
        text: 'About',
        link: '/about',
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task to achieve and I was able to do it in the following way.
See the following code below.

```
    <v-list-item v-for="([icon, text, link], i) in items" 
     :key="i" 
     link 
      @click="$vuetify.goTo(link)" >

      <v-list-item-icon class="justify-center">
        <v-icon>{{ icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="subtitile-1">{{
          text
        }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
```

As per the documentation as we specify the link prop in the item it will be considered as an href to perform navigation.
Then you can make use of the click function and pass the parameter link inside it.