# How to highlight selected item in the Vuetify menu?

Tags: vue.js, menu, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have a menu in the sidebar (*using vue-router*):

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-tile
        value="true"
        v-for="(item, i) in menu"
        :key="i"
        :to="item.path"
    >
        {{item.name}}
    </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

and it works just fine, however I don't see anything in the `Vuetify` docs about highlighting the selected menu item. Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**: it turns out I am not very bright. setting `value="true"` property ensures all elements are always active, removing that resulted in proper function. duh!

Comment: i left the question here in case someone else had a similar run in with the code, if you downvote, at least have the decency to explain why

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586022/router-link-with-vue-and-vuetify-confusion

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vuetify will by default highlight the active link element by matching against the current route.

> [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l761m0069m) example.

However, if need be, you can control this behavior as shown in the API documents for `v-list-tile` and the [active-class](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#api) property. You can manually match the current route to the list item using  something similar to:

```
<v-list-tile 
    v-for="(item, i) in menu"
    :key="i"
    :to="item.path" 
    active-class="highlighted"
    :class="item.path === $route.path ? 'highlighted' : ''"
>
    {{item.name}}
</v-list-tile>
```

See also the [linkActiveClass](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#linkactiveclass) in the Vue Router docs.

Comment: for some reason all items in the menu are set as highlighted when i add this code

Comment: you should make sure the `$route.path` is unique for every next link.

Comment: Can this method be used to expand a ```v-list-group``` based on the current ```$route.path```? I tried this ```:value="$route.path === '/welcome' ? 'true' : 'false'"``` but keeps group expanded even when the path changes. Thank you @DigitalDrifter

Answer (score 0):

Set the prop `exact` for `list-item` to `false`, if you want it to be still highlighted when navigating to subpages