# vuetify 3 v-list highlighting active item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

First off, I am not a front-end dev, so please bear with me. I'm trying to upgrade a legacy project from Vue/Vuetify 2 to 3, and having issues with event handlers not discussed in the upgrade/migration guide.

I have this v-list:

```
<v-list density="compact" @update:selected="this.setSelected">
  <v-list-item
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.title"
    link
    nav
    :disabled="item.disabled"
    :prepend-icon="item.icon || null"
    :title="item.title"
    :value="item.routeName"
  />
</v-list>
```

Later in the file:

```
<script>
import AppLayoutContent from '@/components/AppLayoutContent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'AppLayout',
  components: {
    AppLayoutContent,
  },
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Home',
        icon: 'mdi-home',
        routeName: 'Home'
      },
      {
        title: 'Settings',
        icon: 'mdi-cog-outline',
        routeName: 'Settings',
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    setSelected(routeName) {
      if (routeName && this.$route.name !== routeName) {
        this.$router.push({ name: routeName[0] })
      }
    }
  }
```

The active v-list-item would be the one where `this.$route.name === routeName` is true.

I've tried all sorts of things, but nothing seems to work. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123358/how-to-highlight-selected-item-in-the-vuetify-menu) seems *close*, but I can't get it to work (possibly because they're using `v-list-tile` and not `v-list-item`?). I figure I probably have to do something with https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list/#props-selected , but there's zero documentation on how to use this

In the Vue2 version, we had

```
  computed: {
    selected: {
      set(selected) {
        const { routeName } = this.items[selected] || {}
        if (routeName && this.$route.name !== routeName) {
          this.$router.push({ name: routeName })
        }
      },
      get() {
        return findIndex(
          this.items,
          ({ routeName }) => this.$route.name === routeName
        )
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Your old syntax should still work in Vue3. Why are you using `routeName[0]` when `routeName` is clearly a `string`? You're basically pushing only the first letter of `routeName`, which most likely doesn't match an existing route.

Comment: when it gets to the method, for some reason it is a `string[]` instead of a `string`. Probably because in theory multiple things could be selected? It took me like 2 hours of debugging to realize this. Really annoying. That's coming from the `@update:selected="this.setSelected"` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the [`:to`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-to) prop to create the links, Vuetify will handle activation for you automatically (you can change the class for active items with the [`:active-class`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-active-class) prop).

So you could just do:

```html
<v-list-item
  v-for="item in items"
  :to="{name: item.routeName}"
  ...
/>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } = VueRouter
const vuetify = createVuetify()


const app = {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        {
          title: 'Home',
          icon: 'mdi-home',
          routeName: 'Home'
        },
        {
          title: 'Settings',
          icon: 'mdi-cog-outline',
          routeName: 'Settings',
        }
      ]
    }),
}
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: '/', name:'Home', component: app },
    { path: '/', name:'Settings', component: app },
  ]
})

createApp(app).use(vuetify).use(router).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card class="ma-4">
      <v-list density="compact">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          link
          nav 
          :disabled="item.disabled" 
          :prepend-icon="item.icon || null" 
          :title="item.title"
          :value="item.routeName"
          :to="{name: item.routeName}"
        ></v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@4.2.1/dist/vue-router.global.min.js "></script>
```

---

If you want to set the active state manually, v-list-item has an [`:active`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-active) prop that highlights the item if the provided value is true. So in your case that would give you:

```html
<v-list-item
  v-for="item in items"
  :active="item.routeName === $route.name"
  ...
/>
```

Have a look at the snippet to see how it looks

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
    data: () => ({
      activeItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          title: 'Home',
          icon: 'mdi-home',
          routeName: 'Home'
        },
        {
          title: 'Settings',
          icon: 'mdi-cog-outline',
          routeName: 'Settings',
        }
      ]
    }),
    methods:{
      onSelect(selection){
        const [itemTitle] = selection
        this.activeItem = !itemTitle ? null : this.items.find(item => item.title === itemTitle)
      }
    }
}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card class="ma-4">
      <v-list density="compact" @update:selected="onSelect">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          link
          nav 
          :disabled="item.disabled" 
          :prepend-icon="item.icon || null" 
          :title="item.title"
          :value="item.routeName"
          :active="activeItem?.routeName === item.routeName"
        ></v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      </v-card>
      Active item: {{activeItem ?? 'none'}}
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```