# Vuetify router not working when called from JavaScript?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, router

I am trying to navigate the router from methods in Vuetify, but when putting a /path on the go() function, the whole page just refreshes, and navigates nowhere.

Works:

```
<v-btn router to="/somepage">Goto page</v-btn>
```

Doesnt work (page just refreshes):

```
this.$router.go('/somepage')
```

Works (history go one step back):

```
this.$router.go(-1)
```

Browsing the $router object in the Chrome console, it looks just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your router setup, do you ever  add the '/somepage' path to the router? If you're not sure that that means, take a look at [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript)

Comment: Yes, and the v-btn works just fine with the same path. Also, I have a "*" path added in case I mistype any paths.

Comment: And what's the component you are navigating to?

Comment: I have tried to put paths to many of the pages I have, none of them works. All of them are  Vuetify view components. The whole app is working fine with plenty of pages navigated exclusively using the router through the markup. I have not needed to use the JavaScript call before now. To debug I have tried to use the JavaScript call from many different areas of my code (different views, components, etc.), but the same thing happens, it won't route and page just refreshes.

Comment: Okay, so as a sanity check/typically speaking, part of the router setup would involve defining the route with the path and component being navigated being passed into the Vue Router object which is then injected into the whole Vue instance typically.


If you never define this, then your path will fall through and land on the catcall you have. This typically would be in the index page, which can partially explain the behavior you currently have. I would just check the router setup and see what paths are explicitly mapped to see if the pages that do work are mapped in there and vice versa.

Comment: The router setup is clean as far as I can see, and if it was not, the Vuetify markup routes should fail as well I believe? I am trying to read the Vuetify source to see if they do anything special with the route "to" handling.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586022/router-link-with-vue-and-vuetify-confusion). That may be of use to you.

Comment: The markup versions just simply converts the route links to <a href="/somepage">, that was a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue router provides [several functions for programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

### `this.$router.go(n)`

The `go(n)` function **expects `n` to be a `number`** and is the number of steps forward or backward in the history to travel. I think this is the reason you're not getting the result you expect.

### `this.$router.push(path|route)`

If you'd like to supply an actual path to the function, you should use `push()` instead of `go()`. For example to go to the "home" page you might use `this.$router.push('/')` or to go to the profile page `this.$router.push('/profile')`. Importantly, when you use `push()` the path you submit gets added onto the history stack.

### `this.$router.replace(path|route)`

If you do NOT want to add an entry to the history stack, you should use `replace()` instead of `push()`. Otherwise, the usage of `replace()` is the same as `push()`, i.e. `this.$router.replace('/')` or `this.$router.replace('/profile')`.

### Using a `path` vs using a `route` object

When navigating with `push(path|route)` and `replace(path|route)` you have the option to use a `path`, which is just a string that is the URL of the place you want to go, or using a `route` object. The [route object](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object) gives you a lot more control and allows you to send route or query parameters to the destination component.

For example, if you want to navigate to the profile page for the user with an `id` of `3`, you could do something like `this.$router.push({ path: '/profile', params: { id: 3 } })`. Alternatively, if you're using a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html), you could substitute the route name for the path, i.e. `this.$router.push({ name: 'profile', params: { id: 3 } })`. The `name` should correspond to the name assigned to the route wherever you've set up your main `Router` instance.

### Using Vuetify's `v-btn` component

If you're using a [Vuetify button component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/) there is NOT a `router` attribute. Instead you'd just specify the `to` attribute and Vuetify should automatically interpret it as if it were a `router-link`, e.g. `<v-btn to="/profile">My Profile</v-btn>`. Alternatively, you can use a `route` object, e.g. `<v-btn :to="{ path: '/profile', params: { id: 3 } }">Profile</v-btn>`. Importantly, notice the colon (`:`) preceding the `to` in the second case. This tells Vue to interpret the attribute value as JavaScript instead of plain text.